# I want to insert id that is coming from other table but something is wrong with my query

Tags: php, mysql

I want to insert id that is coming from other table but something is wrong with my query

```
INSERT INTO transport_assign_students 
(`transport_route_time_id`,`student_id`,`bus_stop`)
VALUES (SELECT(transport_route_time_id FROM transport_route_time WHERE bus_stop='indora'), 10017,'indora');
```

Comment: can you add the table architecture?

Comment: it gives me 0 in transport_route_time_id what is wrong with that

Comment: 'it gives me 0 in transport_route_time_id' - doubt it, this statement is syntactically invalid, either use insert..values or insert..select you cannot mix values and select like this.- it looks like you need insert..select.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the insert select this way

```
    INSERT INTO transport_assign_students (transport_route_time_id,student_id,bus_stop) 
    SELECT transport_route_time_id ,  10017,'indora'
    FROM transport_route_time 
    WHERE bus_stop='indora'
```